# Access VBA - OnLoad event fired when an other form is opening

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a weird behaviour when opening a form in my Access db. When I open the form called "Main", even before Main.Form_Open event, an other form ("form_B") is being open, the full sequence of event (Open, Load, etc).

This creates an error since in Main.Form_Open procedure I'm setting variables that are required by Form_B.

I've did a Compile, and a Compact & Repair, and the issue is still there.

If I rename Form_B, when Main is behing open, I'm getting the error saying that Form_B couldn't be found.

The temporary solution I've found was to delete the Main form and replace it with an old version. Then everthing works. But I'd like to understand how something is being executed even before the On_Open procedure.

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Something is wrong with the new form, if the old works. So, use the old form or rebuild the form from scratch.

Comment: Sometimes weirdness is caused by corruption that cannot be explained nor fixed.

Comment: Sounds like Access thinks that Form_B is a subform of the Main form. (Perhaps it was at an earlier time?) -- Subforms are loaded before their parent forms, see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/order-of-events-for-database-objects-e76fbbfe-6180-4a52-8787-ce86553682f9#bm3) - "Working with subforms".

Answer (score 0):

**Ok solution found**. At some point the form Form_B was loaded in a subForm in Main and Main was save like that.

This was not showing since during the OnOpen the subform.sourceobject is being set to Blank_Form, but it was enough to create the error.